# Get current user id in Cron job

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I have tried getting current user id in Cron job to schedule task but its saying  **Trying to get property of non-object**

```
public function handle()
{
    $data = MenterRequest::where('mentor_provider_id','=',Auth::user()->id)->first();
    $this->info('Deleted request successfully');
}
```

Now can I get currents user data.

Comment: Laravel Task Scheduling (cron job) can't use the `Auth::user()` because the tasks are called server side and not by an user.

Comment: @DestinatioN,Ok thank you.

Comment: Can you provide reason behind getting user id at cron job ?

Comment: you need to find an alternate of getting user id.

Answer (score 2):

When you construct your job pass the user (or just the user id) as a param to the constructor like

```
 $theJob = new SomeJob(\Auth::user());
```

Your Job..

```
 public function __construct(User $user)
 {
    $this->user = $user;
 }

 public function handle()
 {
    $data = MenterRequest::where('mentor_provider_id','=',$this->user->id)->first();
    $this->info('Deleted request successfully');
 }
```

If you have a proper relationship setup between your User and MentorRequest you could do something prettier like

```
 public function handle()
 {
    $data = $this->user->mentor_requests->first()->delete();
    $this->info('Deleted request successfully');
 }
```

Or even nicer - you can encapsulate the delete of the mentor_request on your User model in a function for re-use (for example called `deleteMentorRequest()` ) and then do

```
 public function handle()
 {
    $this->user->deleteMentorRequest();
    $this->info('Deleted request successfully');
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

What about using the standard php function: `getmyuid()` ?

then your code will become:

`$data = MenterRequest::where('mentor_provider_id','=',getmyuid());`

Comment: It gives integer 501

Comment: Then you didn't tried getting the current user id , because this is what you just got. Are you trying to get current user NAME ?

Comment: Or are you trying to get the user id of the requester, at the HTTP level ? Because, in a cron , you are not in an http request, your laravel app doesn't have any information about the current user.